# Should I be concerned about this compareTo/equals/hashCode implementation?

Tags: java, implementation, equals, hashcode, compareto

I'm in the middle of QA'ing a bunch of code and have found several instances where the developer has a DTO which implements Comparable.  This DTO has 7 or 8 fields in it.  The compareTo method has been implemented on just one field:

```
private DateMidnight field1;  //from Joda date/time library

public int compareTo(SomeObject o) {
   if (o == null) {
      return -1;
   }
   return field1.compareTo(o.getField1());
}
```

Similarly the equals method is overridden and basically boils down to:

```
return field1.equals(o.getField1());
```

and finally the hashcode method implementation is:

```
return field1.hashCode;
```

`field1` should never be null and will be unique across these objects (i.e. we shouldn't get two objects with the same `field1`).

So, the implementations are consistent which is good, but should I be concerned that only one field is used?  Is this unusual?  Is it likely to cause problems or confuse other developers?  I'm thinking of the scenario where a list of these objects are passed around and another developer uses a Map or Set of somesort and gets unusual behaviour from these objects.  Any thoughts appreciated.  Thanks!

Comment: On a tangent… Users of [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) should note the field in question is of a type ( [`DateMidnight`](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/DateMidnight.html) ) which is now deprecated and should be avoided. The appropriate type now would be [`DateTime`](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/DateTime.html), with a call to [`withTimeAtStartOfDate`](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/DateTime.html#withTimeAtStartOfDay--) as needed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I suspect that this is a case of "first use wins" - someone needed to sort a collection of these objects or put them in a hash map, and *they* only cared about the date. The easiest way of implementing that was to override `equals`/`hashCode` and implement `Comparable<T>` in the way you've said.

For specialist sorting, a better approach would be to implement `Comparator<T>` in a different class... but Java doesn't have any equivalent class for equality testing, unfortunately. I consider it a major weakness in the Java collections, to be honest.

Assuming this really *isn't* "the one natural and obvious comparison", it certainly smells in terms of design... and should be very carefully document.

Comment: Yes, I think "first use wins" is a good way to put this design and why I feel slightly uncomfortable with it.  You're right, Comparator seems a better fit here.

Comment: @Chris: You're absolutely right to feel uncomfortable with it. Comparator is a better fit for sorting... it's just such a shame there's no way to do the same for equality :( (In .NET there's `IEqualityComparer<T>` which is used for this purpose.)

Answer (score 2):

Strictly speaking, this violates the Comparable spec:

http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html

> Note that null is not an instance of any class, and e.compareTo(null) should throw a NullPointerException even though e.equals(null) returns false.

Similarly, it looks like the `equals` method will throw NPE on `equals(null)` instead of returning `false` (unless of course you "boiled" out the null handling code).

> Is it likely to cause problems or confuse other developers?

Possibly, possibly not.  It really depends on how large your project is and how widespread/"reusable"/long-lived your object source code is expected to be used:

- Small/short-lived/limited use == probably not a problem.
- Large/long-lived/widespread use == counter-intuitive implementation may cause future problems

Comment: Yes, I did "boil" out the null handling code of the equals implementation, but thanks for pointing out the lack of null pointer exception for comparable.  Didn't know about that one.

Answer (score 2):

You shouldnt be concerned with it, if field1 is *really unique*. If it`s not, you may have problems. Anyway, my advise is to do some unit tests. They should show the truth.

Comment: +1 for unit tests (of which the developer sadly neglected to write any explicit ones for this)

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you need to be concerned. The contract between the three methods is kept and it's consistent.

Whether it's *correct* from a business logic point of view is a different question.

If e.g. field1 maps to a primary key in the database it's perfectly valid. If field1 is the "firstname" of a person, I would be concerned